# What should we greet a person at 10 o'clock in the night?

Tags: greetings

**This actually had happened** when I was about to relieve a medical officer from his duty at night. I was appointed for the night-shift and had to relieve my co-worker from his evening shift.

Which way I greet a person whom I am meeting **at night 10 o'clock (or for that sake up till midnight).** One ore thing, this is the case wherein I'm meeting that person for the first time in a 24-hr clock (day? night?).

> Good evening doc! What's the order for the patients tonight (or is it today?)? 
>   Good night doc! What's the order for the patients tonight (or is it today?)?
>   Good astronimical dusk *(huh!)* doc! What's the order for the patients tonight (or is it today?)?

Comment: I'd definitely prefer the 1st one. (evening, tonight)  After midnight, I'd switch to (morning, this morning)

Comment: "Good astronimical dusk" is exceptionally strange. Where did you get that from? If you used that, the most likely reaction would be something like this http://www.thedistractionnetwork.com/images/goofy-babies-059.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good evening.  Good night is definitely for good-bye's only, not as a greeting.

As to whether you'd use "today" or "tonight", that might be a convention of that profession, or that particular set of people, so I don't think anyone can give you a single good answer for that.

Comment: That's because the medical order (of medicines) are for that night/morning. Say, one of the scheduled medicines is an injection to be given at 3 am. So collectively, what is the order for the patient tonight or today?

Comment: You could use both. "Tonight" would refer to the current time of day, but "today" could be seen as to refer to "this time around", "this work shift".

Comment: +1 for **good night is definitely for goodbyes only**. It would be wrong to greet someone with "goodnight".