# Usage of different times of the day

Tags: usage

Generally what it is the time of the day whether morning, afternoon, evening or night. We wish everyone *good morning* then start the conversation, *good afternoon* then conversation begins and similarly with *good evening*. Why don't we say *good night* first and then start a conversation? It's again one of the time of the day.

I'm expecting other answers than just *because after that we sleep* that's why it is asked at last.

Comment: You may want other answers besides "after that we sleep," but that might still be the best answer we can give.

Comment: Related: *[What should we greet a person at 10 o'clock in the night?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16361)*

Answer (score 4):

You are asking about what Malinowski called phatic language. It is language that serves a social function that is not conveyed by the literal meaning of the words. "Good morning" in the sense that you are considering is a greeting; "good night" is a farewell. There is nothing in the literal meaning of the phrases that indicates those different meanings: language, and particularly phatic language, is not a logical structure.

Comment: Yep. When my roommate who works an overnight shift comes down for his breakfast by twilight at 8pm, we say *good morning* to him, and if I see him as he trudges to bed at 7am with the sun shining bright, I wish him a *good night*.